# Assigning Access rights on a file in VSS

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

how can i assign modify rights on the a file on VSS to a particular user in a team and the rest of team have ready only rights.

For Example, there are 4 users in the VSS and I want that one user should only be edit a particular file and the others 3 user should only be view that file, can't not edit it.

Thanks in Advance
Hussain

Answer (score 0):

Access control is not that granular in VSS. You can assign particular rights by folder, but not by file. To control the rights by folder open up the Administrator tool, click on a user and select Tools | Rights by project. I suppose you could place a file in a particular folder to accomplish what you want, but that is about the best you can do.

By the way, mainstream support of VSS will end in 2011. It might be a good time to begin moving to an alternate solution. VSS is considered to be the lowest of low in the source control area anyway so any option will be better than VSS.